# Mock web responses in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, mocking, response

We are creating a web application which will communicate with an API of another service to pull data etc..

The problem is that the API is not built, however we do the the JSON format what will be returned when the API is implemented.
How do I mock out any GET responses before we the API is implemented? WE've written code to handle requests by using a load method that reads our sample JSON. What I want to do is use a gem, like WebMock for example to call the request as planned in production, but intercept it and pass the sample JSON back as the response.

There are a lot of examples of this being implemented in tests, but I can't find any to run in development mode.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a file in `config/initializers`:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  stub_request(:post, "www.example.com").to_return(:body => "yourjson")
end
```

Would that work for you?